# Add full path for imported project in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, ns-3

I am using Qt Creator as an IDE for ns3. I followed the steps in this [Wiki Page](https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/HOWTO_configure_QtCreator_with_ns-3) to to do that.

However, since I am not using qmake as my build command and I am using waf command which is used by ns3 the Qt Project generates (.includes) file which contains all the relative paths to the include directory for the imported project. It does not generate .pro directory as usual.

So my question, how can I add a full path to this file so I can access some classes out of the scope of my project?

This is an example of what .includes file contains for an imported ns3 project:

```
build/src/virtual-net-device/bindings
build/src/visualizer/bindings
build/src/wave/bindings
build/src/wifi/bindings
build/src/wimax/bindings
doc
examples/stats
src/antenna/model
src/aodv/doc
src/aodv/helper
src/aodv/model
src/aodv/test
src/applications/bindings
src/applications/doc
```

I tried to add full path to the header file I want to access its fields, but the parser does not recognize it.

Comment: You could create a dummy .pro file, add all sources to the "project" and add all directories containing your headers to the `INCLUDEPATH` qmake variable in .pro file.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov I tried it, but it did not work. I think Qt does not consider the dummy pro file. Because Qt does not show parsing bar when I modify this file